# What's up with the .NIB -> .XIB?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nib

What's up with the NIB->XIB change somewhere between XCode 3.0 to 3.1?
Is there any difference with this name change that I should know while I go through tutorials that mention nothing but the .nib file?

Answer (score 49):

XIB's are very cool. they are basically an un-compiled NIB (in XML format if memory serves me)

during the build process they are converted to NIB's to be deployed in the final product.

Comment: Is that so it will work nicely with a repository system like git/svn?

Answer (score 26):

As I understand it, xib files are **x**ml n**ib** files. xib files are compiled into nibs when the application is built. The xib format was created because nib files don't mesh well with version control (because they're not text), whereas a plain text xml file works well.

Comment: You're correct about what they are. Another reason they were created is because .NIB files can be edited in IB, but are in a non-human-readable binary format. The XML format makes it much easier to tweak something by hand (if necessary) or see what changed from one revision to the next.

Answer (score 17):

The other answers and link explain *what* XIB files are, but not about the specific change.

The new flat-file **.xib** format was introduced with Leopard (and Xcode 3.0) in 2007, but I believe that **.nib** remained the default, primarily for compatibility with older versions of Xcode and OS X. With Xcode 3.1, there was a shift to **.xib** as the preferred format. However, most documentation hasn't been updated, probably in part because the distinction is fairly minor from the standpoint of a normal developer.

I definitely echo the sentiment that XIB files are much better than NIB files, especially when using version control. (Flat files are much easier to manage than directory packages in most tools.)

Answer (score 2):

the **XIB** file (**X**ML **I**nterface **B**uilder) was introduced into Xcode because **NIB** files (**N**xt **I**nterface **B**uilder) weren't so user/editable friendly. XIB's are designed in the format of a raw XML document making it a human-readable source code. Although the older bundled NIB files where editable, they were still a tiny bit more complicated than just a simple XIB, They contained multiple files including the XML XIB. Now most NIBs are compiled and are not readable by anything except for your Mac so it can read them. Apple started using compiled NIB files because people could read and understand the code put into other peoples programs :o. Xcode uses the "ibtool" command to compile nibs now.
If you wish to know more about compiled Nibs go to my detailed answer at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726400/what-is-the-difference-between-nib-and-xib-interface-builder-file-formats/33005499#33005499)