# What is the difference between NIB and XIB Interface Builder file formats?

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder

What is difference between nib and xib in Interface Builder files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's up with the .NIB -> .XIB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068191/whats-up-with-the-nib-xib)

Comment: Wondering when xib was introduced? I was too! Probably between October 2007 and July 2008, as it was introduced between XCode 3.1. [source for XCode version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068191/whats-up-with-the-nib-xib), [source for XCode version date](https://xcodereleases.com/)

Answer (score 99, accepted):

> As of Interface Builder version 3, a new file format (with extension .xib) has been added, which is functionally identical to .nib, except it is stored in a flat file, making it more suitable for storage in revision control systems and processing by tools such as diff.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_Builder#Design

Comment: xib is stand for xml interface builder

Answer (score 32):

The **XIB** File is basicly a source document of a **NIB** File, **XIB**s can nearly always be edited in Xcode *(unless they are outdated or corrupt)*. while the newer **NIB**s are compressed and are unopenable, The older **NIB**s are bundles which can be viewed by Xcode, The Bundled **NIB**s contain some source/archived files which includes `designable.nib` which is often just the renamed **XIB** File.

---

> **NIB** = **N**xt **I**nterface **B**uilder (NXT = NextStep = NS)
>
> **XIB** = **X**ml **I**nterface **B**uilder

---

Although the new archived **NIB** files are unopenable to most applications including Xcode, they can still potentially be unarchived. I found this freeware application called ***NibUnlocker*** On The [CharlesSoft](http://www.charlessoft.com) Website which can potentially disassemble a flat **Nib** file and export it as an **XIB** document. This application is still fairly buggy but it is sometimes very accurate based on the **Nib**s contents.

(NibUnlocker is a very inaccurate name, Nibs are not locked they are archived)

---

[**Click to Download NibUnlocker**](https://www.charlessoft.com/NibUnlocker.zip)

---

If You wish to know a bit more you can read some additional information I have provided below in regards to the **NIB** and **XIB** Formats:

> **Nxt Interface Builder Anatomy:**
>
> Flat **NIB**s
>
> A Flat NIB file is complicated file to analyse but this is not impossible. The structure of these files is just an apple binary property list (begins with "bplist00") and some of its contents are archived through NSKeyedArchiver. Since a **NIB** is formatted as a property list, This allows a small hack: if you actually change the extension of a flat **Nib** to .plist, eg. `ArchivedNib.nib` to `ArchivedNib.plist` You will actually be able to open it in Xcode viewing it as a Property List although not all of the values will be shown because Xcode doesn't know how to display some values (CFKeyedArchiverUID values). When you view a **Nib** as a property list you will probably get a few base properties such as $version, $objects, $archiver and $top.
>
> **Useful Notes**
>
> A **CFKeyedArchiverUID** object is simply a redirector, in the {value = xx}, the value is an *index* for a item in the $objects array (from the start of the array). eg. `<CFKeyedArchiverUID 0x60800002bc20 [0x7fffef6b8c30]>{value = 29}`, value = 29, the result would be the 29th item in the $object's array (Just Remember the array starts with 0). In Objective C you can retrieve this value from a CFKeyedArchiverUID with this method :

```
+ (NSUInteger)valueForKeyedArchiverUID:(id)keyedArchiverUID {
  void *uid = (__bridge void*)keyedArchiverUID;
  NSUInteger *valuePtr = uid+16;
  return *valuePtr;}
```

> (I found this out myself using the internet and later I used [Hopper](http://www.hopperapp.com) to disassemble [NibUnlocker](http://www.charlessoft.com) and I noticed in its source code, it uses the same technique by loading the **NIB** into an *NSDictionary* and going through all its connections, objects, etc.. and writes out a new **XIB**)

yo hit me up with an upvote if this helped ;-)

Answer (score 21):

XIBs are flat files rather than being a bundle. This makes it easier for SCM(source control management) systems to deal with. When you compile your app, the XIB is compiled into a NIB file for inclusion in your app.

The compiled NIB that is included in the app bundle is no longer editable in Interface Builder and is much smaller than the equivalent XIB or legacy NIB file.

Answer (score 13):

Also when you compile your project, .xib file will get compiled into nib.

Answer (score 3):

Functionally nothing but the xib is a source control friendly format