# Where are the UITableViewCell's initialized?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xib

I've created my own `CustomTableView` and `CustomCell`. The cell is in a `xib`, and I'm registering it when initializing the tableView, like this:

```
[self registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCell" bundle:nil] 
                    forCellReuseIdentifier:kCustomCellIdentifier];
```

If I don't do this, I won't be able to define what `ReuseIdentifier` should "point" to this class. This is my `cellForRow`:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
                        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell = [self dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
                        kCustomCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(!cell)
    {
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" 
                        owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

        cell.delegate = self;
        [cell initialSetup]; //Other stuff
    }
    else
        [cell resetCell];

    //And other awesome stuff

    return cell;
}
```

This 'works'. When I lauch my app, my own custom cells are showing.
However, it turns out the cell is NEVER returned as `nil` from `[self dequeue..`. Thus, the if-statement `if(!cell)` is never true. I have additional setup inside this statement that I want to perform, but I don't know where the cell's are being initialized the first time now. If I remove `registerNib`, then this statement is true, but then it's true for all cells, and none will ever be dequeued.

I can probably work around this, and put my `initialSetup` (and other stuff) inside the `-(id)initWithCoder..`-method in the CustomCell-class, but I'd like to know where my cells are being initialized right now. Why do my cells exist before `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: Are you using `storyboard`?

Comment: Then `if(!cell)` will not be true since `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` returns a cell. Use `awakeFromNib` method in `CustomCell`

Comment: @Akhilrajtr But isn't the point of `dequeue..` that I'm re-using my own cells? The way I imagine it is that, at launch - NO cells have been queued. I never made any, so how can they've been queued, right? Then when I scroll 10 rows down, my very first created cell will be queued rather than deallocated, so that I can use it later. When I need the 11th cell, it first checks with this queue by calling `dequeueReusable..`. Since my first cell has been queued, it will be returned here. This makes sense to me.
If you guys are saying `dequeue` always return a cell, then I don't understand anything.

Comment: And all the examples I see everywhere puts `if(!cell)` after `dequeueReusableCell..`.
Also, what is the difference for me by using `awakeFromNib` rather than `-initWithCoder`?

Comment: If there is no existing cell that can be recycled, storyboard will automatically make a new copy of the prototype cell and return it. So the `cell` in `cell = [self dequeue...` will never nil.

Comment: You can find the difference between `awakeFromNib` and `initWithCoder` from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15508041/should-i-be-using-awakefromnib-or-initwithcoder-here)

Comment: @Akhilrajtr Ok, thanks. So is there a way for me to check in `cellForRow` if `dequeueReusable..` returned a new "automatically made" cell or if it's one of my old cells?

Comment: override `prepareForReuse` method of `UITableViewCell`

Answer (score 2):

When you register a class or a nib in a table view using method `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier`or `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier` the tableview internally will create an instance of the cell if no one is available when you call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`, so initialization code is no longer needed inside the delegate.

From the `UITableView.h` code:

```
// Beginning in iOS 6, clients can register a nib or class for each cell.
// If all reuse identifiers are registered, use the newer -dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: to guarantee that a cell instance is returned.
// Instances returned from the new dequeue method will also be properly sized when they are returned.
- (void)registerNib:(UINib *)nib forCellReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
- (void)registerClass:(Class)cellClass forCellReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
```

Depending of the which `register` method is used the `init` methods called are:

- `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier` for cells registered using `registerClass:`
- `initWithCoder:` for cells registered using `registerNib:`

If you are using `registerNib:` you can use too `awakeFromNib` method in the cell, that is also a good place to put initialization code of the cell. The main difference between using `initWithCoder:` or `awakeFromNib` its explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15508041/should-i-be-using-awakefromnib-or-initwithcoder-here).

When a cell is reused, you have the method `prepareForReuse` in the cell to make some cleanup in the cell and left it prepared to be configured again.

A good approach to work with all of this will be:

```
//ViewController code

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...
    [_tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CellSample" bundle:Nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
    ...
}

- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
   //configure the new cell, no if (!cell) needed
   return cell;
}


//Cell code

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        //You can put initialization here
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    //But is better initialize here
}


- (void)prepareForReuse
{
    //Reuse and reset the cell here
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

When using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: forIndexPath:` you don't have to alloc the cell like you would if you were using default `UITableViewCell`. In your custom `UITableViewCell` subclass, this is called when it is initialized:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
     [super awakeFromNib];
}
```

So add that in there and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style
              reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
    //custom your cell
    }
    return self;
  }
```

Comment: Usually it is a good idea to provide some explanation as to why, or how this answers the question in addition to just code.