# Swift set width and height of subclass UIView

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch

I am subclassing an UIView that is being loaded from a xib file. When I load the xib into the Viewcontroller using NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibName() I want the UIView's width, height and background color to be set. This is what I have in the initializer, but when I run the simulator the UIView does not have a width, height or background color set.

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    self.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 150)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override `awakeFromNib` instead. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15508041/1445366) for a broader explanation.