# What is difference between XIB and NIB?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xib, nib

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's up with the .NIB -> .XIB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068191/whats-up-with-the-nib-xib)

I want to know what is difference between xib and nib,I know some thing like xib = xml interface builder and nib is next interface builder,but I am not clear with difference between both ,please help me for it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is worded better than the supposed duplicate. Here is another duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726400/what-is-the-difference-between-nib-and-xib-interface-builder-file-formats

Answer (score 47, accepted):

A Xib is more or less an XML document, it is the uncompiled read/write version of a nib. Once you compile a xib it becomes a nib.